# singularity of the solution to an integral equation

Tags: differential-equations, cv.complex-variables

I consider a function $x\mapsto f(x)$ which is the positive solution to the integral equation

$$\int_{f(x)}^\infty \frac{du}{u^\gamma-x}=1, \quad x\ge 0,$$

where $\gamma\in (1, 2]$ is some parameter. It is not difficult to see that $f$ is analytic on a small neighborhood of $0$. I'd like to know the location of the singularity of $f$ most close to $0$.

The background is that $f$ is the Laplace transform of a certain finite measure. If we know the singularity of $f$, then we can have some tail estimates of the initial measure.

The case $\gamma=2$ is trivial. In this case, we can solve the integral equation and find that $f$ equals $\sqrt x\coth\sqrt x$. Then $f$ has a singularity at $-\pi^2$. Does anyone has any idea in the general case or in the case $\gamma=\frac{3}{2}$, where the integral equation takes a relatively simple form?